# How to read a file being uploaded using KoaJS?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, koa, koa2

I want to upload a file to my KoaJS server and read the content instead of saving the file on the server and do something with that data. How can I achieve it?

I'm using [angular-file-uploader](https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader) to upload the file from the front-end to the backend over a POST REST web service API. And in KoaJS server side, Im expecting to get the file object in `cts.request.files.file`. However, I'm not getting the `ctx.request.files` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use `koa-body` middleware (just like in [this example](https://github.com/koajs/examples/blob/master/upload/app.js)).

Answer (score 0):

To upload files you need to use the `koa-body` package. When you import it you need to specify a couple of options:

1. That you will be uploading form/multipart data
2. And also which directory you want to upload to, see the example below:

```
const koaBody = require('koa-body')({multipart: true, uploadDir: '.'})
```